# Add table of Content To PDF REAder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios-simulator

i developed a app with VFR Reader a open source for pdf reader in github [Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)

so i want to add a table of content with chapiter title and number of a specific page

like in this tutorial : 
[Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-adding-a-table-of-contents-to-an-ipad-reader/)

the probleme i see this tutorial and i passed more than 2 days to add this in Reader sample code but i can't do this

so if Samoan have a idea in how do this table of content in this project it's will be this verry nice to share it

thanks